# grep equivalent of the kwrite regex [A-Z][A-Z]+

Tags: text-processing, grep, regular-expression, kwrite

So, it took me ages, but I finally learned to *think* in terms of regular expressions, thanks to using them in `kwrite`.

But I still don't know how to translate that knowledge to `grep`. I love my `grep`, when I know what I'm doing with it, but the manual has always given me a headache.

I'd like to match stuff like the following lines:

```
CAPITALSFOLLOWING anewline.
CAPI
TALSFOLL owing
ANEW line.
```

That is, lines that begin with two or more capital letters. But I can't figure out how.

In `kwrite`, I would match these lines using:

```
\n[A-Z][A-Z]+
```

But `grep`... hmm. I have a feeling like it's something like:

```
me@ROOROO:~/$ grep "^[A-Z]something" filename
```

but

```
me@ROOROO:~/$ grep "^[A-Z][A-Z]+" filename
```

doesn't work (returns an empty file). A google search for the term 'grep match one or more occurrence' lead me to believe that

```
me@ROOROO:~/$ grep "^[A-Z][A-Z]*" filename
```

was the right syntax. But, alas, that doesn't do the trick.

Comment: In the old days, each tool had its own regexp syntax. By default, `grep` uses its traditional syntax; use `grep -E` to have a more habitual syntax where a backslash followed by a non-alphanumeric character is never special.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using the right syntax in your first example; the problem is `+` is only considered special when using "extended" regular expressions. From the man page of the GNU implementation of `grep`:

> #### Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions
>
> In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (, and ) lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions \?, \+, \{, \|, \(, and \).

(`\?`, `\+`, and `\|` are non-standard GNU extensions though).

So, you either need to escape the `+` (assuming GNU `grep` or compatible):

```
$ grep "^[A-Z][A-Z]\+" filename
```

Use the standard `\{1,\}` equivalent of GNU's `\+`:

```
$ grep '^[A-Z][A-Z]\{1,\}' filename
```

or even here:

```
$ grep '^[A-Z]\{2,\}' filename
```

Or turn on extended regular expressions, by passing `grep` the `-E` flag or just running `egrep` (`egrep` is the command that introduced those extended regular expressions in the late 70s):

```
$ grep -E "^[A-Z][A-Z]+" filename
$ egrep "^[A-Z][A-Z]+" filename
```

In any case, all those would be functionally equivalent to:

```
$ grep '^[A-Z][A-Z]' filename
```

So you don't even need the `+` operator.

In your other example you tried:

```
$ grep "^[A-Z][A-Z]*" filename
```

`*` works in basic regular expressions, but it matches 0 or more times, not 1 or more. The solution in [your answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31402/73) works because it says "match a capital, then another capital, then 0 or more capitals". The method in the question says "match a capital, then 1 or more capitals", which is the same. You can also use `{min,max}` to specify exactly how many you want, and if you leave out `max` it allows any number (this also requires extended regular expressions):

```
$ egrep "^[A-Z]{2,}"
```

(as a history note, `egrep` didn't support `{min,max}` initially (and still doesn't in Solaris 11 `/bin/egrep` for instance). `\{min,max\}` support was added to `grep` before `{min,max}` was added to `egrep` (which in the case of `egrep` did break backward compatibility)).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add an extra [A-Z]. So, it's

```
me@ROOROO:~/$ grep "^[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]*" filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a regexp support from `perl`. Form `man grep`:

```
   -P, --perl-regexp
          Interpret  PATTERN  as  a Perl regular expression.  This is highly experimental
          and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.
```

So `grep -P "^[A-Z][A-Z]+"` could be more helpful.